# Trying to make a TextView clock, app freezes on launch

Tags: android, time, while-loop, textview, sleep

I'm trying to simply pull the system time, and input it into the TextView, wait one second, then update it.  I use a while loop for this, though when the app starts, it freezes, with no display.  Am I doing something wrong? perhaps a better way to do this? I need the method to have the ability to pull the integers so I can match them to set ones, I hope to add in an alarm feature.

#### MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.polyphaser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void timeUpdate() {
        boolean loop = true;

        while (loop = true) {
            String currentTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

            // textView is the TextView view that should display it
            TextView sysTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
            sysTime.setText(currentTimeString);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This show how to use a handler:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable;

    private TextView sysTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sysTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timeUpdate();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void timeUpdate() {
        String currentTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

        // textView is the TextView view that should display it
        sysTime.setText(currentTimeString);
    }
}
```

Comment: My English is not enough to explain that. Search internet for handle and runnable. You may start [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to do this is with a handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sysTime.setText(...
    }
}, 1000);
```

I'm pretty sure the while loop locks up your main thread which is why it freezes.
Check out the handler at the dev pages.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

You need move while loop into its own thread, so far you are sleep on UI thread, which means all UI drawing things are blocked. When you need update UI in second counting thread, call Activity.runInUIThread(new Runnable(...){...}) to post the update.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem wrong, look at this line in your code:

```
while (loop = true)
```

I'm guessing the compiler optimizes out that statement (loop is already true, loop = true does not evaluate to a boolean, and furthermore, loop cannot be accessed by anything to change its value to false) and so you have a while (false) which results in the body of your loop never executing.

- You should have that update occur in another read and update the textview using runonuithread.